# exception handling

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>  
using namespace std;  
#include <exception>  

void dis()
{
    cout<<"terminate disabled "<< endl;
}

void display() throw(int,double)    
{
    if(0)  
        throw int();  
    if(0)  
        throw double();  
    if(1)  
        throw string();  
}  

int main()  
{     
    set_unexpected(dis);  
    try  
    {  
        display();      
    }  
    catch(int)  
    {
        cout<<"int "<< endl;
    }  
    catch(double)  
    {
        cout<<"double "<< endl;
    }  
    catch(string)  
    {
        cout<<"string "<< endl;
    }  

    system("pause");  
    return 0;  
}
```

now the output was

```
terminate disabled
```

and then the program terminated

but instead of set_unexpected when i wrote

```
set_terminate(dis);
```

the output was

```
terminate disabled  
terminate disabled
```

why this dicrepancy?

Comment: You should not include headers below a `using namespace std;` statement.

Comment: @als it is  Mingw port of GCC as given on the internet

Comment: I'd rather get rid of the exception specifications than figure them out.  Exception specifications can be difficult to get and keep right, work really badly with templates, and complicate the type system, among other things.

Answer (score 1):

So, it's not entirely clear what your original output was. I tried to clean it up as best as I could, but your quote tags make it unobvious.

In your code, if you use `set_unexpected(dis)`, you should see:

```
terminate disabled
```

In your code if you use `set_terminate(dis)`, you should see:

```
terminate disabled
```

In your code, if you use both `set_unexpected(dis)` and `set_terminate(dis)`, you should see:

```
terminate disabled
terminate disabled
```

One way to get around this, is to have dis `throw 0` as the last line. That would allow you to convert your exception to something that your function claims that it will throw.

Comment: I don't understand, in his code, displa() throw string(), and in his main(), string exception is caught, isn't it? why is dis triggered?

Comment: @Alcott: He uses an [exception specifier](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/exceptions/). Because of this, the function should only return the types specified there.